# Synchronization issue with JMS and JPA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, asynchronous, eclipselink

I have a situation where I need to receive parts of a large file over `JMS`(grouped messages) and store it in DB.

The problem is that each message in group will be one row in `TABLE A`  and there is `@ManytoOne` realtionship to `TABLE B`. Which means the for one group there will be only one entry in table B but many entries in table A.

My current logic is such that before inserting in `table A`, I'm checking for any entries(@NamedQuery, as the primary key would NOT be known to the `MDB` at that time), and if not found, creating a new one(creating the primary key of `Table B` here).

Since there are multiple instances of `MDB` receiving the messages in same group, the entries in `table B` are getting duplicated for same message group, since the transaction in MDB which first created entry for TABLE B is not not comiitted yet.

To be more clear:

Step 1: Receiving the message.

Step 2: Create the entitiy required for TABLE A. Check whether there's any entries with same group ID in table B(`READ`), if found, set the relationship and persist, if not, create a new entity for table B(`WRITE`) (with generated primary key by a service) set the relationship and persist.

The issue is, multiple instances of MDB creates entry for table B, since it not able to find the entry(created by the first MDB) during `READ`, hence `WRITING` new entries for same group ID.

Is there any way I can overcome this problem ?
1. I'm using eclipselink and Oracle , Container managed transaction and entity managers are injected using @PersistenceContext annotation.

Thanks

Comment: as having more than 1 mdb doesn't guarantee you higher throughput (guessing that in your use case the db is the biggest factor), would it be a solution to limit the allowed number of MDB instances to 1?  Easy to do via the deployment descriptor.  Glassfish server?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are doing?  Are you trying to prevent both transactions from creating a new A, or only a new B?

You can add a unique constraint on the A foreign key in the B table.  This will ensure the second attempt to insert a B for the A will fail.

Another solution is to use a pessimistic lock on the A for the transaction, this will ensure the transaction do not conflict.

You could also use an optimistic lock by forcing the version of A to increment, this will cause the second attempt will fail.  Actually since A has a ManyToOne to B, its version should increment, so you should get a lock error already.